# cant change photo properties in css

Tags: css

Hello my image inside css code is not responding on code, you can see on the screen vh=10 but screen is on full size.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COVxv.png)

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 2):

First Wrap img with div and give image width and height and then try fixing size to div.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define at least *width* and *height*, even if you're putting an "auto" on one of these. Also, try *object-fit* propreties if your image is in a separated  tag, or *background-size* and *background-position* propreties if you want to keep it as your background.

Hope it'll help !

Comment: vh is responsive :)

Comment: all right, my bad

Comment: good answer, you can edit the answer by clicking the edit button